# Sharpe Ratio Pandas Calculation based on Trades

Tags: python, machine-learning, finance

I am trying to get a calculation for the Sharpe Ratio in Python.
I have a pandas Dataframe that contains trades with their buy and selling date, buy and selling price, absolute and relative profits. It looks like the following:

```
Date        Buy_Price   Sell_Price  Profit_abs  Profit_rel_in_percent   Buy_Date    Sell_Date
2005-04-14  1.330714    1.42        0.089286    6.709629                2005-04-14  2005-05-23
2005-10-12  1.758929    2.208929    0.450000    25.583753               2005-10-12  2005-11-03
...
```

Now I would like to calculate the Sharpe Ratio based on this data. Any idea? And maybe a python implementation?
I found this, but I think thats not correct or is it?

```
# Calculate daily returns by dividing sell price by buy price and subtracting 1
df['Return'] = df['Sell_Price'] / df['Buy_Price'] - 1
    
# Calculate average daily return by taking the mean of daily returns
avg_daily_return = np.mean(df['Return'])
    
# Calculate standard deviation of daily returns using numpy's std function
std_daily_return = np.std(df['Return'])
    
# Calculate Sharpe ratio as the ratio of average daily return to standard deviation of daily returns, scaled by the square root of the number of trading days in a year
sharpe_ratio = sqrt(len(df)) * avg_daily_return / std_daily_return
```

Thanks!